# Can't access tomcat externally in Centos 7

Tags: centos, firewall, centos7, tomcat, tomcat8

I just installed tomcat 8 on a Centos 7 server and I know it's working because I could get tomcat's index.html with wget http://localhost:8080. (I couldn't think of another way of testing in a remote server). Now I want to access it externally but whenever I try `http://[server's public ip]:8080` from the computer I use to ssh to the server I get a timeout.

I've seen several answers that suggest modifying firewalld so I did that and now it looks like this: 
[image: firewall current status]

I've reloaded with `sudo firewall-cmd --reload` but still all I get is a timeout from the server.

Does anyone know what else am I missing?

Comment: Check the IP address  which tomcat is listening on (using `ss` or `netstat`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being the network management before the server. The company policy wasn't allowing any inbound traffic via those ports to that server. Once the exception was added I could connect to tomcat from any network and I didn't have to change anything else on the server's firewall. As @sc0der said, the ports added to the firewall where added permanently as well as the http and https services.

Answer (score 1):

There are some checks you need to do:

1. Check if you add the port 8080 permanent in `firewall` after reloading it
2. Do you use any `cloud providers` e.g AWS? then remember to open the port
3. Check the `SELinux` policy for the opening ports and in the war in `webapps` directory